# Need help to save recent searches in localStorage - React/Redux

Tags: html, reactjs, local-storage

I am using foursquare api for searching places to eat. I want to save recent searches made by the user in local storage and show 10 searches in the sidebar. When user clicks on them it will redirect them to that search result page. Can somebody point me in the right direction as how to achieve this in react/redux architecture?

Here is the codesandbox link if you want to take a look at the app.

https://codesandbox.io/s/koj4484zqo

Comment: Im down voting this because the question references to a code sample which does not exist anymore, taking a context from the question in place

Comment: Even if you limit it to just 10 entries, localStorage is still not the right candidate for this job.

Answer (score 3):

you don't really need to use `redux` for this feature. You can just serialize the data you would like to store and objectify it when u would like to use it. An easy example is following.

```
class YourClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
        this.saveToStorage = this.saveToStorage.bind(this);
        this.recover = this.recover.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //check for localStorage every time component mounts. You can also do this conditionally.
        this.recover();
    }

    recover(){
        //parse the localstorage value
        let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('history'));

        this.setState({history: data.history});
    }

    onChangeHandler(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({input: e.target.value});
    }

    saveToStorage(){
        //local storage only takes in key value pair so you would have to serialize it.
        let history = this.state.history ? this.state.history : {history: []};

        history.history.push({text:this.state.input, link:'store linke here'});

        localStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify(history));
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                <Button onClick={this.saveToStorage}>
                    Save
                </Button>
                <div className="your-side-bar">
                    {this.state.history ? this.state.history.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            //render as state changes
                            <Link to={item.link}>{item.text}</Link>
                        )
                    }) : 'no history'}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code but you get the idea.